# ClearFloat with Twitter Bootstrapper

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtjmsy/8BDRj/

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
        <img src="http://autooccasion76.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/clio_rs1.gif" class="img-polaroid">
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        <span class="labelColorBlue">Statut:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <INPUT type="Text" value="Valeur" name="TxtBox">              
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="span2 offset2" style="background-color: blue">...</div>

</div>​
```

I have an image, a label a textbox and a blue rectangle, all span2, what I want to get is

the bluebox be placed left to the image and under the label and textbox

I tried out clearfix or offset classes, they all placed my blue rectangle under the image, how can I made it placed just under the height of the label and textbox and on the right side of the picture whatever its height ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid is designed to stack rows vertically, and stack columns horizontally. You have to think your layout on those principles.

If I understood correctly, you should use two columns : one for the image, the other for the rest. This second column would be divided in two rows : the label+input and the blue bar.

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/8BDRj/2/)

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
        <img src="..." class="img-polaroid">
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <span class="labelColorBlue">Statut:</span>
            </div>
            <div class="span8">
                <INPUT type="Text" value="Valeur" name="TxtBox" />              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12" style="background-color: blue">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Be careful with the input, because it has its own width that should be overridden to fit in a column, like [that (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/8BDRj/3/) : `<INPUT class="span12" ... />`

Keep in mind that the fluid grid has 12 columns each time you create a descendant (think %). Check the [fluid grid nesting doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) if you have doubts.

Comment: Hi Sherbrow, thanks for your answer, I didn't think that way, excellent cheers...